# Searching a hash table with singly linked list in c

Tags: c, struct, hashtable, cs50, singly-linked-list

I'm new to C
I'm trying to check if a word is in my hash table or not.
But I'm getting a segmentation fault.

This is my code for the function
It should return true if the word is found or false if not

```
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // Hashing the word
    unsigned int hc = hash(word);
    // Creating a node for traversing
    node *ch = malloc(sizeof(node));
    // Traversing
    ch->next = table[hc];
    C = false;
    while (ch->next != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(ch->word, word) == 0)
        {
            c = true;
            break;
        }
        ch = ch->next;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Is it `cs50`? If yes, add that tag.

Comment: `malloc` returns uninitialized memory. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to check it but it returns true for some elements then gives segmentation fault

Comment: U mean I should not initialize the node?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Searching for *anything* in a hash table should *not* require allocation(s), so that alone should be an indication you're doing something wrong. A proper [mcve] is required for us to tell you where things are going wrong (besides the unnecessary allocation we can already see). The nondescript globals `c`, `C` aren't helping either. Please remember: we don't know *anything* about your code beyond what you post here. We're not mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

For starters neither the variable `C` used in this statement

```
C = false;
```

nor the variable `c` used in this statement

```
c = true;
```

are declared.

This allocation of a node

```
node *ch = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

does not make a sense and produces a memory leak.

Also it is unclear whether for the given string the function `hash`  returns a valid value of an index in the array `table`.

Provided that the function `hash` indeed returns a valid index then the function `check` can be defined the following way

```
bool check( const char *word )
{
    // Hashing the word
    unsigned int hc = hash( word );

    // Traversing
    node *head = table[hc];

    while ( head != NULL && strcasecmp( head->word, word ) != 0 )
    {
        head = head->next;
    }

    return head != NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- You only need to `malloc` when you create a node, for example when you insert an item into the table. If you just want to traverse the list in a bucket, create a pointer variable that visits all elements one by one. That variable is either a pointer to an existing node in the list or `NULL`.
- When you traverse the list, you look at the nodes in isolation. You don't need to access `next` until you move to the next node.

Your function might look like this:

```
bool check(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hc = hash(word);
    node *ch = table[hc];

    while (ch != NULL) {
        if (strcasecmp(ch->word, word) == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        ch = ch->next;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This should work provided that `hash(word)` produces valid hash table indices and that all head nodes of the bickets have been initialize to ´NULL`.